# Will react-native-firebase play nice with an Expo detached app?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

I have a detached Expo (v25) based app and I'm looking for a solution for Push Notifications for both iOS and Android.

On iOS - I'm currently using RN's PushNotificationIOS API and it's working great.

On Android - I'm considering using a package like [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) or [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification), WDYT? What should be my first step here?

Thanks :)

Comment: I am also using detached Expo app and running from XCODE. How can I debug react native code now? like we did for simple react-native app in browser.

Comment: @yogendarji On the iOS Simulator, open the Expo menu and select "enable remote debugging" - it will open a new browser tab, then open the console - you'll have it there.